# customtkinter _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyautogui, customtkinter

i'm writing a login code with python, using the customtkinter library. In this code, i put an image on background, however, when i run this code, the program was stoped and i recive that error "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nd\Desktop\Script\arquivo.py", line 57, in <module>
    background = ctk.CTkLabel(tela2,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\nd\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_label.py", line 104, in __init__
    self._update_image()
  File "C:\Users\nd\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_label.py", line 141, in _update_image
    self._label.configure(image=self._image.create_scaled_photo_image(self._get_widget_scaling(),
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1692, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

And that is the code who i'm writing:

```
while True:
    if not py.locateOnScreen(fr"{here}\\imagens\\erro_login_easy.png", confidence = 0.8):
        tela2 = ctk.CTk()
        tela2.title("Desktop - Login Easyware")
        tela2.geometry("1280x720")
        tela2.resizable(False, False)
        tela2.configure(fg_color = "#FAFAFA")
        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
        tela2.iconbitmap(fr"{here}\imagens\desktop.ico")
        img2 = ctk.CTkImage(light_image = Image.open(fr"{here}\imagens\login.png"),
                            dark_image = Image.open(fr"{here}\imagens\login.png"),
                            size = (1280, 720))
        background = ctk.CTkLabel(tela2,
                                  text = None,
                                  image = img2)
        background.place(x = 0, y = 0)
```

For a better context, that is a automation to make a login automatically in a program, so i use the py.locateOnScreen to find the message "login done successfully",if it is not found, it will run the GUI, to make a new login or password.

I really don't know what can i do, someone can help me? I need this for yesterday, and i cant find the resolution nowhere.

Ps: I'm from Brazil, please ignore all the gramatical error, i'm still learning english. Thanks!

Comment: Hey guys, i found the error, it was a indentation error... Basically, i was trying call the "tela2" variable, but in the full code, he wasn't indentation properly, so "tela.mainloop()", wasn't in the right place. I'm sorry if did you lost yout time reading this, but if you had the same error in the same way, congratulations, probrably you found the answer!

Comment: You could close the question now...